# Can't get function to work

Tags: matlab

I am unable to write a function to generate a matrix.
I keep on getting the error "Not enough input arguments" when I try to run the following:

function B=generate_matrix(n)
    B=zeros(n,n);
    %I'll add more stuff to the function once I can get it to work
end

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've checked online already and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: As long as you're calling the `B = generate_matrix(m)` with `m` defined or using an integer literal like `B = generate_matrix(7)`, it should work. Is the function in your present working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write file for the function

`function B = generate_matrix(n)
B = zeros(n,n);
end`

then, in the command window,

`B = generate_matrix(3)`

this should generate the 3x3 zero matrix. I think your code is working.

Comment: It hasn't been working for me. I have the exact code above in a .m file but every time I click run I get the error "not enough input arguments". Is there some way I should be loading the function onto the command window? Sorry for the dumb question. I'm really new to MATLAB.

Comment: @migs: is the .m file named `generate_matrix.m`? Is your current path set right? (you can check this by right clicking the function file tab in the editor and then clicking 'Change Current Folder to...').

Answer (score 2):

The error message you have is perfectly normal.

You have defined a function which requires one input:

```
function B = generate_matrix(n) 

B = zeros(n,n);
```

When you press the `Run` button (or `F5`), Matlab attempts to execute the code. Or Matlab does not know what is `n`, hence the error message. Actually, the `Run` button *only* works for scripts or functions with no inputs.

So, to use your function you have to *call* it (*e.g.* from the workspace) and specify an argument:

```
>> generate_matrix(3)
ans =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

Note that this argument can be a variable that has been previously defined.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your give input for the variable n. If n is null you will get this error. In the command window first assign value to n. Say `n = 5`. Then run your program. Since n already has a value, your program will work fine.

Comment: The thing is, I want to be able to call the function for arbitrary n. Much in the same way that you can write A=zeros(100) B=ones(6) and C=zeros(7) in the command window.

Comment: since `n` is the input for the function generate_matrix, `n` should be defined for the function to work.

Comment: What I basically want to do is write a function and then be able to run my program and use that function from the command window-- like in Python. Would this be possible? I feel that if n has to be an actual fixed number then this isn't exactly what I want

Comment: I guess command line execution is not possible like python but, you can use `input()` function for that. Refer: [Tutorial on input function](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/input.html)

But make sure to remove the `n` from your function definition. You function should look like this:

`function B = generate_matrix() 

n = input("enter the matrix size);

B = zeros(n,n);

end`

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it out.